# Unable to find certain views in my .axml layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I got compilations errors in the activity class that says " edit_password ID not found" as well as the other IDs in the same .axml file. Does anyone know why?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
           android:background="@color/basic_button_background"
           style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
          >
           <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:singleLine="true"
               app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
               android:id="@+id/edit_password"
               android:textSize="@dimen/margin_padding_size_medium"
               android:privateImeOptions="@string/abc_action_mode_done"               
           />
       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your `.axml` file ,clean and rebuild your project. It should then regenerate the `Resources.designer.cs` file which should include your `Id` definition.

Comment: I find the IDs when I search for missing for them.
I think this happens when there is a problem in the .xml file, then all the IDs that are related to this .xml file will cause an error. It happened to me a few times when I had duplicated tags in the file. I got the same error
The question is what is the problem in the .xml file that caused this error :(

Comment: could you show your complete  `.xml` ? Do you miss `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in the root layout

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer :)
You are right. I have forgotten to add this link you have mentioned:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

but in addition  to it, I had to use `android:inputType="textPassword"` so the toggle work

Thanks a lot for inspirations :)